# why is my docker container not working

Tags: linux, dockerfile

I was trying to start up a web application in a docker container

here is my dockerfile

```
FROM centos:6

EXPOSE 9980

RUN yum install -y wget

RUN wget --no-cookies --no-check-certificate --header "Cookie: gpw_e24=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.oracle.com%2F; oraclelicense=accept-securebackup-cookie" "http://download.oracle.com/otn-pub/java/jdk/8u60-b27/jdk-8u60-linux-x64.rpm"

RUN yum localinstall -y jdk-8u60-linux-x64.rpm

RUN mkdir /usr/local/apps

WORKDIR /usr/local/apps

COPY ac-gui ac-gui/

RUN mv /etc/localtime /etc/localtime.bak

RUN ln -s /usr/share/zoneinfo/America/Chicago /etc/localtime

RUN chmod 775 ac-gui/start.sh ac-gui/stop.sh

ENTRYPOINT ["ac-gui/start.sh"]
```

start.sh

```
#!/bin/sh

export APP_HOME=/usr/local/apps/ac-gui
export JAVA_HOME=/usr/java/jdk1.8.0_60
export PATH=$JAVA_HOME/bin:$PATH

export PID_FILE=$APP_HOME/ac-gui.pid


cd $APP_HOME

$JAVA_HOME/bin/java -server -jar ac-gui.war --spring.config.name=ac-gui >> ac-gui.log 2>&1 &

echo "$!" > "$PID_FILE"
```

if I run

> docker run -i -t -p 9980:9980 ac-gui bash

and run ac-gui/start.sh inside the container, it works fine for me.

but if I just run the container as

```
docker run -d -p 9980:9980 ac-gui
```

the container will be exited (0).

is there anything I did wrong?

Comment: I think you are missing the ENTRYPOINT on the Dockerfile

Comment: @HemersonVarela I just update my dockerfilem, but the result is still the same, any idea? Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just found out the cause of this problem from
[this question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28214133/5001083)

so just remove the & in my start.sh will resolve the problem