# Cannot return to shell session after script

Tags: linux, bash, docker, supervisord, alpine-linux

I cannot get a script to return to bash.

The script is kicked off via the following Docker directives:

```
ENTRYPOINT ["/bin/bash", "-c"]
CMD ["set -e && /config/startup/init.sh"]
```

The init script looks like this:

```
#!/bin/bash

if [ -d /etc/postfix/init.d ]; then
    for f in /etc/postfix/init.d/*.sh; do
        [ -f "$f" ] && . "$f"
    done
fi

echo "[x] Starting supervisord ..."
/usr/bin/supervisord -c /etc/supervisord.conf

bash
```

And this is the command I use to kick off the image into a container:

```
docker run -it --env-file ENV_LOCAL mailrelay
```

The init script runs as expected (and I see output from the scripts within the `/etc/postfix/init.d/` directory and `supervisord` kicks off Postfix.

The problem is getting the script to return to the parent process (bash) instead of needing to start a new one. After it hits the `supervisord` the session sits there, requiring a Ctrl+C to get it to get back into a `bash` prompt.

If I leave off the call to `bash` at the end of the `init.sh` script, Ctrl+D exits the script AND the container, returning me to the host OS (osx). If I replace the `bash` call with `exit`, it returns to the host OS as well.

Is `supervisord` behaving the way it's supposed to, by running in the foreground this way? I'd like to be able to easily get back into the container shell session to check to see if things are running. Am I left with needing to Ctrl+D (into the secondary `bash` session) in order to do this?

**UPDATE**
Marc B

> take out the bash line, so you don't start a new shell. and if
>   supervisord doesn't go into the background automatically, you could
>   try running it with & to force it into the background, or maybe
>   there's an extra cli option to force it to go into daemon mode

I've tried removing the last call to `bash`, but as I've mentioned it just sits there still, and Ctrl+D takes me to the host OS (exits the container).

I just tried `/usr/bin/supervisord -c /etc/supervisord.conf &` (and left off the call to `bash` at the end) and it just immediately returns to host OS, exiting the container. I assume because the container had nothing left to "do", and so stopped.

Comment: if you want to get back to the parentl shell prompt, why are you firing up a NEW bash at the end of the script? that kicks you into that child bash, not the parent one.

Comment: Yes, how do I get back to the parent one?

Comment: take out the `bash` line, so you don't start a new shell. and if supervisord doesn't go into the background automatically, you could try running it with `&` to force it into the background, or maybe there's an extra cli option to force it to go into daemon mode

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
#!/bin/bash

if [ -d /etc/postfix/init.d ]; then
    for f in /etc/postfix/init.d/*.sh; do
        [ -f "$f" ] && . "$f"
    done
fi

echo "[x] Starting supervisord ..."
/usr/bin/supervisord -c /etc/supervisord.conf
one
bash # You are spawning a new bash shell here. Remove this statement
```

At the end your're stuck in a **child** bash shell :(

Now if you're not returning to the parent shell, the last command that you have run is the culprit.

```
/usr/bin/supervisord -c /etc/supervisord.conf
```

You can either force the command to run in the background by

```
/usr/bin/supervisord -c /etc/supervisord.conf & #the & tells to run in background
```

A workaround for keeping the container open is mentioned [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28212380/why-docker-container-exits-immediately)

Comment: This seems to work, except that the container exits I presume because the script completes and so bash (PID 1) terminates, which then the Docker daemon stops...

Comment: @AVProgrammer: See [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28212380/why-docker-container-exits-immediately)

Comment: Thanks @sjsam I've decided to run supervisord as PID 1 and use `/etc/supervisord.conf` (the helpful include directive) to kick off the scripts that init.sh is kicking off (with process specific config). Thank you.