# Docker container A dies after excuting query(insert/update) in cassandra running as another docker service B

Tags: python, docker, cassandra, microservices

I am new to docker,Cassandra . 
well I'm facing a weird issue, any help as how I could debug this issue would be great. I am using

```
 Cassandra 3.3.0, 
native Cassandra-driver for python- 3.3.0 
Docker 1.11.1
```

I have two containers one is hosting cassandra service say container A and from the other container say B i'm performing an insert query to cassandra container.
here once B executes the query to A just after this container B which is my service container dies .

**Logs that i see in container B**

```
[start] application exit with code 0, killing container
```

i dont see any other relevant logs to debug further as what is the reason so that i am container dies right after insert.

Just to make sure i am not missing  any exception i am catching all exceptions
i.e BaseException . i have added few loggers their to track my issue however even container dies it never comes to this except block.

**What i suspect**

it seems docker has error in memory and the moment it will write , it dies or something else.

**what  i tried also**

i tried to run my code without docker container to see offending lines  if any. here without docker it works and no exceptions  comes. I also make sure  to shutdown the cassandra session.

Please advise ..

Answer (score 2):

> I dont see any other relevant logs to debug further as what is the reason so that i am container dies right after insert.

That is how a container is supposed to work: once its main command exits (or fail), the container exits as well and put itself in an "Exited" state.

The main command ([`ENTRYPOINT`](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/#entrypoint) or [`CMD`](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/#cmd)) was for container B to insert query to a cassandra container. It does so and exit.

Comment: Here both the container are microservices and needs to be highly available so within CMD if we initiate a monitor to run a method infinitely to keep on interacting with cassandra then it should not die or i am missing something obvious to understand here ?

Comment: With my ongoing understanding with docker i came to know this link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28212380/why-docker-container-exits-immediately . So it looks i need to add some running thread on container B after upsert command. let me verify this i will get back to this post again.

Comment: @Karn_way yes, something must trigger an early stop.