# Terminal with Docker Compose with Links

Tags: networking, docker, docker-compose, environment, docker-container

I would like to link three services together (db, nginx, and web service) under a bridge network and be able to poke at the different services from my localhost or from inside the container, and have an interactive terminal for the web service. How can I achieve this?

My docker-compose configuration is the following:

```
version: '2'
services:
  web:
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: Dockerfile-alpine
    command: /bin/bash
    ports:
      - "5000:5000"
    volumes:
      - $REPO_DIR:/repository
    links:
      - db
      - nginx
  nginx:
    image: nginx:stable-alpine
    ports:
      - "8080:8080"
    volumes:
      - $NGINX_STATIC_DIR:/var/www/static
      - $NGINX_CONFIG_FILE:/etc/nginx/nginx.conf
  db:
    image: mysql/mysql-server
    ports:
      - "3307:3306"
    environment:
      MYSQL_USER: $MYSQL_USER
      MYSQL_PASSWORD: $MYSQL_PASSWORD
      MYSQL_DATABASE: $MYSQL_DATABASE
      MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: $MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD
    volumes:
      - $DB_DATA_DIR:/var/lib/mysql
      - $DB_LOG_DIR:/var/log/mysql
```

where the web service is using the `mhart/alpine-node:6.7.0` as a base and further adds some utilities plus Python3.5 and Flask.

If I do `docker-compose run web`, I get access to an interactive terminal, but the db and nginx services are not booted/linked properly. I get the following output:

```
Starting courseadmin_nginx_1
Starting courseadmin_db_1
bash-4.3#
```

And then further network forensics from inside the container turns up that neither nginx or db are present. I can further support this claim since using `docker-compose up` actually created a port conflict for the db service granted that I have mysql installed on my host system, thing it never reported with `docker-compose run`.

On the other hand, if I try `docker-compose up`, I get a much more active trace, but no interactive terminal:

```
Starting courseadmin_nginx_1
Recreating courseadmin_db_1
Recreating courseadmin_web_1
Attaching to courseadmin_nginx_1, courseadmin_db_1, courseadmin_web_1
db_1     | Initializing database
courseadmin_web_1 exited with code 0
db_1     | Database initialized
db_1     | MySQL init process in progress...
db_1     | Warning: Unable to load '/usr/share/zoneinfo/iso3166.tab' as time zone. Skipping it.
db_1     | Warning: Unable to load '/usr/share/zoneinfo/zone.tab' as time zone. Skipping it.
db_1     | mysql: [Warning] Using a password on the command line interface can be insecure.
db_1     | mysql: [Warning] Using a password on the command line interface can be insecure.
db_1     | mysql: [Warning] Using a password on the command line interface can be insecure.
db_1     | mysql: [Warning] Using a password on the command line interface can be insecure.
db_1     | 
db_1     | /entrypoint.sh: ignoring /docker-entrypoint-initdb.d/*
db_1     | 
db_1     | 
db_1     | MySQL init process done. Ready for start up.
db_1     |
```

What can I do to achieve an interactive terminal and proper linking of my three containers?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not entirely certain I fully understood your question, so I will try to answer the part I can:

At first glance, your `docker-compose.yml` file looks fine, and the correct running of the `docker-compose up` command seems to confirm this. However, you specify `version: '2'`. From the `docker-compose` docs, from Version 2 on, linking is implicitly done by `docker-compose` itself (I'll add the links in the comments as I don't have enough reputation). This means you can remove the `links:` part (unless you seek to explicitly specify these aliases, in which case you can disregard this part). I thought a great resource explaining the difference between V1 and V2 was [this](https://medium.com/@giorgioto/docker-compose-yml-from-v1-to-v2-3c0f8bb7a48e#.a98qbfasc) (he covers `links` in step 2 of the post), but you can of course also check the `docker-compose docs`.

For the rest, my suggestions:

- `docker-compose up -d` will run everything in detached mode. Docker compose will take care of the implicit linking, as long as you have those correctly configured. For more details on inter-container networking with `docker-compose`, [this](https://prakhar.me/docker-curriculum/#multi-container) was a great resource for me. The real stuff on `docker-compose` starts in section 3.3 of that page.
- Once everything is up and running, `docker ps -a` will show you the active containers
- To start an 'interactive terminal', just do `docker exec -it $container_id bash` if I recall correctly. This will start a terminal, in that container. `exec` executes a command in the specified container, while the `i` flag starts an 'interactive' terminal, the `t` flag specifies the TTY layer, and `bash` the type of shell.

If I could add an additional recommendation, add the `depends_on:` class in your `web` configuration. This will make your web container wait for both the SQL and Nginx to have fully started. Like so:

```
services:
  web:
    [...]
    depends_on:
      - nginx
      - db
```

Comment: The `docker-compose` docs I keep talking about can be found here, specifically the part about `links`: https://docs.docker.com/compose/networking/#/links

Comment: Great post! It definitely helps me a lot to progress. However I can't do the docker exec -ti $container_id because my web container keeps dying since the /bin/bash doesn't have anything to do. Is there any way I can keep it alive without passing any entrypoint?

Comment: Just in case you're not clear on **why** your `web` container dies, see [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/28214133/6942595). For the rest, could you detail a little more in your OP what you're trying to attain with your `web` service? To me it seems you could simply do `image: alpine` and it will set up a container into which you can then start a shell with `exec`?

Comment: Ah, I think I misunderstood. To run your alpine container, as per [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/30209974/6942595) answer, just do `command: tail -f /dev/null` to keep the container running.

Comment: Great! This allowed to solve my issue. It's unfortunate that small details like that are not as well documented as the rest of the docker documentation