# My Container Docker always exit immediately after docker start

Tags: docker, dockerfile

I tried to make container using this dockerfile.
sorry, first time create post in stack, so just upload the photo..

I run it with using this :

`docker run -dit -p 8014:80 --name webserver7test2 webserver`
even try without -it

run successfull. if the container stop and I try to start it again but the container always exit immediately.
[image]

try advice from this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37232961) but failed with this log appear.

[image]

really appreciate if you can help me

Comment: Could you post your Dockerfile? so we can see what command you are using and what process you are trying to run to keep the container alive.

Comment: Remove the `-d` flag and then run. This will show you what happens in the container. Also make sure the command that runs doesn't exit or launch a background process. You need to make sure the program runs in foreground

Answer (score 0):

The image shows that your container exited with code 0. That means there was no error and your start command ran and then finished execution.

Make sure you have `CMD <webserver-start-script>` inside your Dockerfile and it should not exit until your container is running. If it exits, docker thinks container is done and stops it.

Answer (score 0):

You docker is exiting because there is no process in the foreground. Docker will exit if no process is found in the foreground. Try adding `tail -f /dev/null` to the last line of your Dockerfile.