# Docker container run standalone but fails in kubernetes

Tags: hadoop, docker, kubernetes

I have docker container (Hadoop installation https://github.com/kiwenlau/hadoop-cluster-docker) that I can run using `sudo docker run -itd -p 50070:50070 -p 8088:8088 --name hadoop-master kiwenlau/hadoop:1.0` command without any issue, however when trying to deploy same image to kubernetes, pod failing to start. In order to create deployment I'm using `kubectl run hadoop-master --image=kiwenlau/hadoop:1.0 --port=8088 --port=50070` command

Here log of describe pod command

```
Events:
  FirstSeen     LastSeen        Count   From                                                    SubObjectPath                   Type            Reason          Message
  ---------     --------        -----   ----                                                    -------------                   --------        ------          -------
  6m            6m              1       default-scheduler                                                                       Normal          Scheduled       Successfully assigned hadoop-master-2828539450-rnwsd to gke-mtd-cluster-default-pool-6b97d4d0-hcbt
  6m            6m              1       kubelet, gke-mtd-cluster-default-pool-6b97d4d0-hcbt     spec.containers{hadoop-master}  Normal          Created         Created container with id 1560ff87e0e7357c76cec89f5f429e0b9b5fc51523c79e4e2c12df1834d7dd75
  6m            6m              1       kubelet, gke-mtd-cluster-default-pool-6b97d4d0-hcbt     spec.containers{hadoop-master}  Normal          Started         Started container with id 1560ff87e0e7357c76cec89f5f429e0b9b5fc51523c79e4e2c12df1834d7dd75
  6m            6m              1       kubelet, gke-mtd-cluster-default-pool-6b97d4d0-hcbt     spec.containers{hadoop-master}  Normal          Created         Created container with id c939d3336687a33e69d37aa73177e673fd56d766cb499a4235e89d554d233c37
  6m            6m              1       kubelet, gke-mtd-cluster-default-pool-6b97d4d0-hcbt     spec.containers{hadoop-master}  Normal          Started         Started container with id c939d3336687a33e69d37aa73177e673fd56d766cb499a4235e89d554d233c37
  6m            6m              2       kubelet, gke-mtd-cluster-default-pool-6b97d4d0-hcbt                                     Warning         FailedSync      Error syncing pod, skipping: failed to "StartContainer" for "hadoop-master" with CrashLoopBackOff: "Back-off 10s restarting failed container=hadoop-master pod=hadoop-master-2828539450-rnwsd_default(562dae39-a757-11e7-a5a3-42010a8401c6)"

  6m    6m      1       kubelet, gke-mtd-cluster-default-pool-6b97d4d0-hcbt     spec.containers{hadoop-master}  Normal  Created         Created container with id 7d1c67686c039e459ee0ea3936eedb4996a5201f6a1fec02ac98d219bb07745f
  6m    6m      1       kubelet, gke-mtd-cluster-default-pool-6b97d4d0-hcbt     spec.containers{hadoop-master}  Normal  Started         Started container with id 7d1c67686c039e459ee0ea3936eedb4996a5201f6a1fec02ac98d219bb07745f
  6m    6m      2       kubelet, gke-mtd-cluster-default-pool-6b97d4d0-hcbt                                     Warning FailedSync      Error syncing pod, skipping: failed to "StartContainer" for "hadoop-master" with CrashLoopBackOff: "Back-off 20s restarting failed container=hadoop-master pod=hadoop-master-2828539450-rnwsd_default(562dae39-a757-11e7-a5a3-42010a8401c6)"

  5m    5m      1       kubelet, gke-mtd-cluster-default-pool-6b97d4d0-hcbt     spec.containers{hadoop-master}  Normal  Started         Started container with id a8879a2c794b3e62f788ad56e403cb619644e9219b2c092e760ddeba506b2e44
  5m    5m      1       kubelet, gke-mtd-cluster-default-pool-6b97d4d0-hcbt     spec.containers{hadoop-master}  Normal  Created         Created container with id a8879a2c794b3e62f788ad56e403cb619644e9219b2c092e760ddeba506b2e44
  5m    5m      3       kubelet, gke-mtd-cluster-default-pool-6b97d4d0-hcbt                                     Warning FailedSync      Error syncing pod, skipping: failed to "StartContainer" for "hadoop-master" with CrashLoopBackOff: "Back-off 40s restarting failed container=hadoop-master pod=hadoop-master-2828539450-rnwsd_default(562dae39-a757-11e7-a5a3-42010a8401c6)"

  5m    5m      1       kubelet, gke-mtd-cluster-default-pool-6b97d4d0-hcbt     spec.containers{hadoop-master}  Normal  Created         Created container with id 8907cdf19c51b87cea6e1e611649e874db2c21f47234df54bd9f27515cee0a0e
  5m    5m      1       kubelet, gke-mtd-cluster-default-pool-6b97d4d0-hcbt     spec.containers{hadoop-master}  Normal  Started         Started container with id 8907cdf19c51b87cea6e1e611649e874db2c21f47234df54bd9f27515cee0a0e
  5m    3m      7       kubelet, gke-mtd-cluster-default-pool-6b97d4d0-hcbt                                     Warning FailedSync      Error syncing pod, skipping: failed to "StartContainer" for "hadoop-master" with CrashLoopBackOff: "Back-off 1m20s restarting failed container=hadoop-master pod=hadoop-master-2828539450-rnwsd_default(562dae39-a757-11e7-a5a3-42010a8401c6)"

  3m    3m      1       kubelet, gke-mtd-cluster-default-pool-6b97d4d0-hcbt     spec.containers{hadoop-master}  Normal  Created         Created container with id 294072caea596b47324914a235c1882dbc521cc355644a1e25ebf06f0e04301f
  3m    3m      1       kubelet, gke-mtd-cluster-default-pool-6b97d4d0-hcbt     spec.containers{hadoop-master}  Normal  Started         Started container with id 294072caea596b47324914a235c1882dbc521cc355644a1e25ebf06f0e04301f
  3m    1m      12      kubelet, gke-mtd-cluster-default-pool-6b97d4d0-hcbt                                     Warning FailedSync      Error syncing pod, skipping: failed to "StartContainer" for "hadoop-master" with CrashLoopBackOff: "Back-off 2m40s restarting failed container=hadoop-master pod=hadoop-master-2828539450-rnwsd_default(562dae39-a757-11e7-a5a3-42010a8401c6)"

  6m    50s     7       kubelet, gke-mtd-cluster-default-pool-6b97d4d0-hcbt     spec.containers{hadoop-master}  Normal  Pulled          Container image "kiwenlau/hadoop:1.0" already present on machine
  50s   50s     1       kubelet, gke-mtd-cluster-default-pool-6b97d4d0-hcbt     spec.containers{hadoop-master}  Normal  Created         Created container with id 7da7508ac864d04d47639b0d2c374a27c3e8a3351e13a2564e57453cf857426d
  50s   50s     1       kubelet, gke-mtd-cluster-default-pool-6b97d4d0-hcbt     spec.containers{hadoop-master}  Normal  Started         Started container with id 7da7508ac864d04d47639b0d2c374a27c3e8a3351e13a2564e57453cf857426d
  6m    0s      31      kubelet, gke-mtd-cluster-default-pool-6b97d4d0-hcbt     spec.containers{hadoop-master}  Warning BackOff         Back-off restarting failed container
  49s   0s      5       kubelet, gke-mtd-cluster-default-pool-6b97d4d0-hcbt                                     Warning FailedSync      Error syncing pod, skipping: failed to "StartContainer" for "hadoop-master" with CrashLoopBackOff: "Back-off 5m0s restarting failed container=hadoop-master pod=hadoop-master-2828539450-rnwsd_default(562dae39-a757-11e7-a5a3-42010a8401c6)"
```

kubectl log output:

```
kubectl logs hadoop-master-2828539450-rnwsd
 * Starting OpenBSD Secure Shell server sshd
   ...done.
```

Note that docker container itself not starting hadoop. In order to start it, I have to connect to container and start hadoop manually, however I want to be able to simply run container in K8s for now.

Thanks

Comment: how do you create the pod? is there volume and other objects specified during the creation?

Comment: @MohammadMahzoun creating with command kubectl run hadoop-master --image=kiwenlau/hadoop:1.0 --port=8088 --port=50070
as mentoned in question. No volumes were specified during pod creation

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The equivalent command in kubernetes is

```
kubectl run -it hadoop-master --image=kiwenlau/hadoop:1.0 --port=8088 --port=50070
```

Actually it's not about kubernetes, there is something wrong in the Dockerfile.

[A docker container exits when its main process finishes.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28214133/692076)

With `CMD [ "sh", "-c", "service ssh start; bash"]`, SSH service is started at the background, after then the container stopped as job finished.

It should be an executable script/program running in the foreground always, like `~/start-hadoop.sh`.

FYI, usually we don't need ssh to the container, as `docker exec -it some_container bash` should be enough.

Comment: Thanks. The problem was in docker indeed, however hadoop must have ssh access from master to slaves and vice versa