# Docker Container Exits Immediately Upon Start

Tags: amazon-web-services, docker, elasticsearch, amazon-ec2

I am trying to run the new Elasticsearch 6.0 docker container on an Amazon Linux AMI (the standard one). I previously had 5.6 running with no issues on a different instance, but my container is immediately crashing when I start it up.

Here's the command I'm using: `docker run -it -p 9200:9200 -p 9300:9300 -d docker.elastic.co/elasticsearch/elasticsearch:6.0.0`

I referenced this post on Docker crashing, but still seemed to run into the same issues: [Why docker container exits immediately](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28212380/why-docker-container-exits-immediately)

I ran docker logs  and get the following response:

```
[2017-11-28T19:00:30,946][INFO ][o.e.n.Node               ] [] initializing ...
[2017-11-28T19:00:31,013][INFO ][o.e.e.NodeEnvironment    ] [eEXrI6m] using [1] data paths, mounts [[/ (overlay)]], net usable_space [4.5gb], net total_space [7.7gb], types [overlay]
[2017-11-28T19:00:31,014][INFO ][o.e.e.NodeEnvironment    ] [eEXrI6m] heap size [989.8mb], compressed ordinary object pointers [true]
[2017-11-28T19:00:31,015][INFO ][o.e.n.Node               ] node name [eEXrI6m] derived from node ID [eEXrI6mGTci22tpTNMMh8w]; set [node.name] to override
[2017-11-28T19:00:31,015][INFO ][o.e.n.Node               ] version[6.0.0], pid[1], build[8f0685b/2017-11-10T18:41:22.859Z], OS[Linux/4.9.62-21.56.amzn1.x86_64/amd64], JVM[Oracle Corporation/OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM/1.8.0_151/25.151-b12]
[2017-11-28T19:00:31,015][INFO ][o.e.n.Node               ] JVM arguments [-Xms1g, -Xmx1g, -XX:+UseConcMarkSweepGC, -XX:CMSInitiatingOccupancyFraction=75, -XX:+UseCMSInitiatingOccupancyOnly, -XX:+AlwaysPreTouch, -Xss1m, -Djava.awt.headless=true, -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8, -Djna.nosys=true, -XX:-OmitStackTraceInFastThrow, -Dio.netty.noUnsafe=true, -Dio.netty.noKeySetOptimization=true, -Dio.netty.recycler.maxCapacityPerThread=0, -Dlog4j.shutdownHookEnabled=false, -Dlog4j2.disable.jmx=true, -XX:+HeapDumpOnOutOfMemoryError, -Des.cgroups.hierarchy.override=/, -Des.path.home=/usr/share/elasticsearch, -Des.path.conf=/usr/share/elasticsearch/config]
[2017-11-28T19:00:32,283][INFO ][o.e.p.PluginsService     ] [eEXrI6m] loaded module [aggs-matrix-stats]
[2017-11-28T19:00:32,283][INFO ][o.e.p.PluginsService     ] [eEXrI6m] loaded module [analysis-common]
[2017-11-28T19:00:32,283][INFO ][o.e.p.PluginsService     ] [eEXrI6m] loaded module [ingest-common]
[2017-11-28T19:00:32,283][INFO ][o.e.p.PluginsService     ] [eEXrI6m] loaded module [lang-expression]
[2017-11-28T19:00:32,283][INFO ][o.e.p.PluginsService     ] [eEXrI6m] loaded module [lang-mustache]
[2017-11-28T19:00:32,283][INFO ][o.e.p.PluginsService     ] [eEXrI6m] loaded module [lang-painless]
[2017-11-28T19:00:32,283][INFO ][o.e.p.PluginsService     ] [eEXrI6m] loaded module [parent-join]
[2017-11-28T19:00:32,283][INFO ][o.e.p.PluginsService     ] [eEXrI6m] loaded module [percolator]
[2017-11-28T19:00:32,283][INFO ][o.e.p.PluginsService     ] [eEXrI6m] loaded module [reindex]
[2017-11-28T19:00:32,283][INFO ][o.e.p.PluginsService     ] [eEXrI6m] loaded module [repository-url]
[2017-11-28T19:00:32,283][INFO ][o.e.p.PluginsService     ] [eEXrI6m] loaded module [transport-netty4]
[2017-11-28T19:00:32,284][INFO ][o.e.p.PluginsService     ] [eEXrI6m] loaded module [tribe]
[2017-11-28T19:00:32,284][INFO ][o.e.p.PluginsService     ] [eEXrI6m] loaded plugin [ingest-geoip]
[2017-11-28T19:00:32,284][INFO ][o.e.p.PluginsService     ] [eEXrI6m] loaded plugin [ingest-user-agent]
[2017-11-28T19:00:32,284][INFO ][o.e.p.PluginsService     ] [eEXrI6m] loaded plugin [x-pack]
[2017-11-28T19:00:34,795][INFO ][o.e.x.m.j.p.l.CppLogMessageHandler] [controller/120] [Main.cc@128] controller (64 bit): Version 6.0.0 (Build 8e6ab35cf803a2) Copyright (c) 2017 Elasticsearch BV
[2017-11-28T19:00:34,834][INFO ][o.e.d.DiscoveryModule    ] [eEXrI6m] using discovery type [zen]
[2017-11-28T19:00:35,513][INFO ][o.e.n.Node               ] initialized
[2017-11-28T19:00:35,513][INFO ][o.e.n.Node               ] [eEXrI6m] starting ...
[2017-11-28T19:00:35,648][INFO ][o.e.t.TransportService   ] [eEXrI6m] publish_address {xxx.xx.x.x:9300}, bound_addresses {0.0.0.0:9300}
[2017-11-28T19:00:35,664][INFO ][o.e.b.BootstrapChecks    ] [eEXrI6m] bound or publishing to a non-loopback or non-link-local address, enforcing bootstrap checks

ERROR: [2] bootstrap checks failed
[1]: max file descriptors [4096] for elasticsearch process is too low, increase to at least [65536]
[2]: max virtual memory areas vm.max_map_count [65530] is too low, increase to at least [262144]
[2017-11-28T19:00:35,675][INFO ][o.e.n.Node               ] [eEXrI6m] stopping ...
[2017-11-28T19:00:35,734][INFO ][o.e.n.Node               ] [eEXrI6m] stopped
[2017-11-28T19:00:35,734][INFO ][o.e.n.Node               ] [eEXrI6m] closing ...
[2017-11-28T19:00:35,745][INFO ][o.e.n.Node               ] [eEXrI6m] closed
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It looks like your error is here:

> ERROR: [2] bootstrap checks failed
>   [1](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/run/#set-ulimits-in-container-ulimit): max file descriptors [4096] for elasticsearch process is too low, increase to at least [65536]
>   [2]: max virtual memory areas vm.max_map_count [65530] is too low, increase to at least [262144]

ElasticSearch is picky on needing enough file descriptors and memory given from it's host; the documentation on their page has some information regarding how you can set this up - depending on what your host is:

https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/docker.html

After adjusting your host per-above, their page there discusses a setup with `docker-compose` however if you would like to still use `docker run` you can find the equivalent commands [here](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/run/#set-ulimits-in-container-ulimit).

Answer (score 1):

You can try adding ulimit section:

```
services:
  elastic:
      image: elasticsearch
      ulimits:
          nofile:
              soft: 65536
              hard: 65536
```

or change the limit in

```
/etc/security/limits.conf
```

you can see the actual limits with

```
cat /proc/<pid>/limits
```

when the process is running.