# Docker container exits after executing entrypoint point

Tags: docker, dockerfile

```
FROM openjdk:8
LABEL maintainer="test"
EXPOSE 8080
ADD test-demo.jar assembly.jar
ENTRYPOINT ["java","-jar","assembly.jar"]
```

The container i start with this docker file exits soon after it starts. Please advice what to do to keep this running.

Comment: It might be a problem with the jar itself. Did you try running `java -jar assembly.jar` from the command line to make sure that doesn't exit? Once you get that working, then you can run the docker image.

Comment: try `docker logs <container_id>` to see what went wrong. If you are not sure aobut the ID, try `docker ps -a` to see all contianers you had

Answer (score 0):

You need to make sure a `java -jar assembly.jar` will keep being active as a foreground process, or said main process would exit, and with it the docker container itself.

You should wrap the `java -jar` call in its own script, which allows various ways to keep that script alive, [as described here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42601940/6309).