# Docker -it option won't work with ENTRYPOINT or CMD in Dockerfile

Tags: docker, dockerfile, docker-image, docker-entrypoint

I'm new to Docker, when I run my docker image with -it option, docker container finishes running, echoed "test" as indicated in my docker file and exited with zero. The expected behavior should be that docker keeps open a virtual terminal of the container:
    `docker run -it test`
Here is my Docker file:

```
FROM centos
CMD echo test
```

I tried both CMD and ENTRYPOINT, and both shell form and exec form, the behavior is the same. However, if I replace the CMD by RUN in the docker file, the -it option can work normally.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why docker container exits immediately](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28212380/why-docker-container-exits-immediately)

Comment: Containers don't have "virtual terminals".  The design point is that a container runs a single reasonably-long-running service, and exits (discarding all of its state) if the service ever shuts down.

Answer (score 1):

Docker requires main process to keep running in the foreground. Otherwise, it thinks that application is stopped and it shutdown the container.

In your case, `-i` means keep STDIN open even if not attached & `-t` means allocate a pseudo-tty. They are just meaningful when the container is running.

But the container running is not depends on the above flags, they depends on the main process. Here, it's `echo test`, it executes and then finish, so the container found the main process finish, it exited.

If you replace `CMD` with `RUN`, then it will use default `CMD`, that is `/bin/bash`, see dockerfile of centos [here](https://github.com/CentOS/sig-cloud-instance-images/blob/24c0d04946b72e37776309224712b5f05aa52639/docker/Dockerfile), and `/bin/bash` will not auto exit, so container not exit.