# Docker container exits even when run with -it

Tags: docker, containers

I am trying to run a custom service in a docker container.  The service is started with `myservice start` - this then forks and daemonises the main process and exits. The main process then listens on a network socket for incoming commands.  The process itself works fine.

In my Dockerfile, I have this as the last two commands:

```
WORKDIR "/app/myservice"
CMD ["bin/myservice", "start"]
```

The image is built successfully.  Now, when I run it like so:

```
docker run -d -p 7890:7890 myimage
```

the container starts and then exits.  In logs, I can see the service starting prior to the container exiting with exit code 0.  This is expected, as the command from the dockerfile exits with code 0.

Looking at [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28212380/why-docker-container-exits-immediately), it seems apparent that if I run it like so:

```
docker run -dit -p 7890:7890 myimage
```

the container should stay running even after the batch script that starts my service exits.  Yet this is not the case - and the container terminates exits straight away.

What am I missing?  How can I get the container to stay running?

Comment: a container lives as long as the command launched is active, maybe add a `; sleep infinity ` or such

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Compare how long live those 2 containers

1) 
`docker run -it ubuntu sh -c "echo Hello ; sleep 3"`

2) 
`docker run -it ubuntu sh -c "while true ; do echo Hello ; sleep 3 ; done"`

Check the doc for CMD

https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/#cmd

and ENTRYPOINT

https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/#entrypoint

When you

`docker run -it ubuntu bash`

as long as you exit from your bash,your container completes and exits.

check also

[What is the difference between CMD and ENTRYPOINT in a Dockerfile?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21553353/what-is-the-difference-between-cmd-and-entrypoint-in-a-dockerfile/21564990#21564990)

`

Answer (score 1):

In general, you don't need to daemonize anything in a container. The common pattern is to start a command that lives forever and print into STDOUT/STDERR.
When/if that command fails, container will stop.
So, remove

> ... then forks and daemonises the main process and exits ...

part and launch your main process.

Answer (score 0):

when container first PID 1(updated!) process is completed(exited with 0 or other) that occur container exit also.

to keep your container alive, the first pid must keep alive also...

In the end of your script myservice, you can add this line `tail -f /dev/null`

Comment: Minor nit, it's pid 1, not 0.