# Why docker container doesn't run

Tags: python, docker, flask

I am trying to run a flask application in a docker on windows, and python 3.7.

This is my flask application:

app.py:

```
from flask import Flask
app = Flask(__name__)
@app.route('/')
def hello_world():
   #some lines of code
   return render_template('home.html', url=url, host='0.0.0.0')

if __name__ == '__main__':
   app.run(debug=True, host='0.0.0.0')
```

Then I created a dockerfile.txt as a DockerFile and put the following contents inside:

```
FROM python:3.7
MAINTAINER <<Your Name>>
RUN apt-get update -y && \
   apt-get install -y python3-pip python3-dev
COPY ./requirements.txt /app/requirements.txt
WORKDIR /app
RUN pip3 install -t lib -r requirements.txt
COPY . /app
ENTRYPOINT [ "python3" ]
CMD [ "app.py" ]
```

Then I run the following comments in command prompt:

```
docker build -t flask-image:latest .
docker run -d -p 5000:5000 --name name-container1 flask-image
```

My problem is that after `docker ps -a` I see container `name-container1` is exited. But have no idea why???

This is output:

```
CONTAINER ID        IMAGE               COMMAND             CREATED              STATUS                          PORTS               NAMES
d925f21f165c        flask-image         "python3 app.py"    About a minute ago   Exited (1) About a minute ago                       name-container1
```

Comment: I had a look at this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28212380/why-docker-container-exits-immediately

Comment: please run `docker logs d925f21f165c` and share what you got from there.

Comment: recommend to use: https://hub.docker.com/r/tiangolo/uwsgi-nginx-flask/ building flask apps inside a docker

Comment: do run the container without -d first. It will then output container console directly to your window. It seems to me, that the app is not starting due to flash mis-config and the container is terminated.

Comment: @eLRuLL `Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "app.py", line 1, in <module>
    from flask import Flask
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'flask'`

Comment: @SimasJoneliunas I got the above error: ModuleNotFoundError...

Comment: Adding `RUN pip3 install flask` to my dockerfile

Comment: looks like a problem with requirements installation, start debugging from there.

Comment: make sure that the requirements file is being installed. And make sure that flask is in the requirements.txt~

Comment: I added Flask==0.12 in `requirements.txt`

Comment: @SimasJoneliunas yes you were right i forgot to install requirements .txt. Thank you very much :x

Answer (score 0):

Most likely PYTHONPATH is not setup in Docker. Instead of `RUN pip3 install -t lib -r requirements.txt`, just install the requirements as `RUN pip3 install -r requirements.txt`

Comment: Now it gives me this error: ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'pandas_datareader'

Comment: Are you still trying to run the code snipped in the original question ? IThere's no `pandas_datareader` reader there. Unless you've added some more code that imports `pandas_datareader` in that case, is there pandas_datareader in requirements.txt ?