# Simple Docker container dies immediatelly after docker run command

Tags: java, docker, dockerfile, devops, alpine-linux

I have a Dockerfile which looks like this:

```
FROM alpine:3.9

RUN apk add --update openjdk8
RUN mkdir /var/generator/
COPY generator.jar /var/generator
EXPOSE 8080
ENTRYPOINT [ "/bin/sh" ]
```

Dockerfile is inside generator/ folder. I am building it using:

```
docker build -t generator generator/
```

It builds successfully:

```
Successfully built 878e81f622cc
Successfully tagged generator:latest
```

but when I am trying to run this image with

```
docker run -d -p 8080:8080 generator
```

it dies immediately. `docker logs` gives no output.

What is wrong with my Dockerfile? Why is the container dying?

Comment: You docker container execute the command  `/bin/sh` and exit. You should have a process running to prevent it from the exit

Comment: Because you use ENTRYPOINT [ "/bin/sh" ] , which meas a null shell , you does not execute generator.jar

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why docker container exits immediately](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28212380/why-docker-container-exits-immediately)

Answer (score 1):

Try to run the JAR. Currently, it just runs `sh` command and exits. Make it something as below to run the JAR in foreground -

```
FROM alpine:3.9

RUN apk add --update openjdk8
RUN mkdir /var/generator/
COPY generator.jar /var/generator
EXPOSE 8080
ENTRYPOINT ["java","-jar","/var/generator/generator.jar"]
```

Answer (score 0):

Beside your entrypoint is wrong (`sh` exits immediately) I would also recommend to start with an appropriate base image instead of starting with alpine and installing the openjdk package. Since you want to run a java application just use the JRE and not a full JDK and start the application as a foreground process.

Here's a minimal version which is also more efficient in disksize as the image will be smaller.

```
FROM openjdk:8-jre-alpine

COPY generator.jar /opt/generator.jar
EXPOSE 8080
ENTRYPOINT ["java","-jar","/opt/generator.jar"]
```