# Why is the container not running after start?

Tags: scala, docker, sbt, sbt-native-packager

I am using https://sbt-native-packager.readthedocs.io/en/stable/introduction.html to build my scala application and would like the publish the application as a local docker container.

I entered the following command:

```
sbt docker:publishLocal
```

I think, everything went fine and I've got an image generated:

```
docker images
REPOSITORY          TAG                 IMAGE ID            CREATED              SIZE
sapmock             0.1                 db261ab225b5        About a minute ago   664MB
<none>              <none>              0940c75d8e5a        About a minute ago   703MB
openjdk             8                   bec43387959a        10 days ago          625MB
```

Why did `sbt` create an image `<none>`?

And when I run the image as a container, it stops immediately:

```
~/scala/sapmock$ docker run -d -p 8080:80 sapmock:0.1
91abf0e00e3a46baa78a09b9eccd3c562ae82d5b058d5e122e8927f8e7307afd

~/scala/sapmock$ docker ps -a
CONTAINER ID        IMAGE               COMMAND                  CREATED             STATUS                     PORTS               NAMES
91abf0e00e3a        sapmock:0.1         "/opt/docker/bin/sap…"   10 seconds ago      Exited (0) 8 seconds ago                       upbeat_brattain

~/scala/sapmock$ docker ps 
CONTAINER ID        IMAGE               COMMAND             CREATED             STATUS              PORTS               NAMES
```

Why?

Resources can be find here: https://gitlab.com/sweetsoft/sapmock

In addition, the content of the generated docker file:

```
FROM openjdk:8 as stage0
WORKDIR /opt/docker
COPY opt /opt
USER root
RUN ["chmod", "-R", "u=rX,g=rX", "/opt/docker"]
RUN ["chmod", "u+x,g+x", "/opt/docker/bin/sapmock"]

FROM openjdk:8
USER root
RUN id -u demiourgos728 2> /dev/null || (( getent group 0 || groupadd -g 0 root ) && useradd --system --create-home --uid 1001 --gid 0 demiourgos728 )
WORKDIR /opt/docker
COPY --from=stage0 --chown=demiourgos728:root /opt/docker /opt/docker
EXPOSE 8080
USER 1001:0
ENTRYPOINT ["/opt/docker/bin/sapmock"]
CMD []
```

Comment: partly a duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/a/28214133/5986907 ... ?

Comment: Do you get any error output? Maybe try without the `-d` first to see the console output.

Comment: I've tried with `docker run -it --name sapmock -p 8080:8080 
"docker run" requires at least 1 argument.
See 'docker run --help'.
` as you can see, I've got an error message.

Comment: Docker is expecting a command and args at the end. Can you run try using: `docker run -it --name sapmock -p 8080:8080 sapmock ./opt/docker/bin/sapmock`?

Comment: but as you can see, the entrypoint is `ENTRYPOINT ["/opt/docker/bin/sapmock"]`