# Unable to start docker container

Tags: spring-boot, docker, docker-compose, dockerfile

I am trying to run spring-boot application through docker container. I am using docker-compose for the same. But the container is not getting UP. It's status is showing always 'restarting X seconds'. I'm unable to find the issue because i can't go inside the container to check  logs. even 'docker logs' giving any response.

Can anyone let me know if there is any way to find the issue.

below is 
docker-compose.yml

```
version: "3"

services:

 test-create-backend:
  restart: always
  build: .
  container_name: test-create-backend
  environment:
   - JASYPT_PWD=${JASYPT_PWD}
  networks:
   - test-proxy
  ports:
   - "8096:8096"
  volumes: 
   - /home/ubuntu/tnc_logs:/TnC/logs

 nginx:
  restart: always
  container_name: nginx
  image: nginx
  networks:
   - test-proxy
  depends_on:
   - test-create-backend
  ports:
   - '80:80'
   - '443:443'
  volumes:
   - './nginx_proxy/conf.d:/etc/nginx/conf.d:ro'
   - './build:/var/www'
   - '/etc/ssl/certs:/etc/ssl/certs:ro'

networks:
 disip-proxy:
    external:
      name: test-proxy
```

below is Dockerfile

```
FROM maven:3.6.0-jdk-11-slim AS build

# Copy the source code
RUN rm -rf /usr/src/app/*
COPY src /usr/src/app/src
COPY pom.xml /usr/src/app
USER root
# Setup working directory
WORKDIR /usr/src/app

# Speed up Maven JVM a bit
ENV MAVEN_OPTS="-XX:+TieredCompilation -XX:TieredStopAtLevel=1"

# Compile the code, run unit tests and pack the fat-JAR file
RUN mvn -T 1C -f /usr/src/app/pom.xml clean package  -DskipTests

# Building the final image with fatjar
FROM openjdk:11-jre-slim
COPY --from=build /usr/src/app/target/test*.jar /home/app/app.jar
ENTRYPOINT java -jar -Dspring.profiles.active=local -Djasypt.encryptor.password=${JASYPT_PWD} /home/app/app.jar
```

Comment: We need to see at least your docker-compose.yml, Dockerfile, and the logs of your spring boot application build to help you.

Comment: See [How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: updated both docker-compose and dockerfile

Comment: Can you replace the screenshots with the actual text of the files, please?

Comment: Please no screenshots :).

Comment: I am sorry... I removed screenshots and updated the actual files

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The container seems to be crashing on boot for some reason. Try to start it using the pseudo-TTY "-dit"  argument to see why its failing

```
docker run -it MYCONTAINER /bin/sh
```

That should give you an idea about why it is crashing.

Comment: You can take it another step back and do docker run -it openjdk /bin/sh , then run the command that you're sending in the ENTRYPOINT,  if that exits immediately then that's the problem, you can refer to this question for the solution [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28212380/why-docker-container-exits-immediately) I could have tested it for you if you actually provided a text compose file instead of a screenshot.

Comment: Actually this helped me , docker run -it openjdk /bin/sh. We had a problem with 'openjdk:11-jre-slim' this image. I used latest .Now, it's working fine. Thank you so much @Bouzid

Answer (score 0):

You should run the built image overriding the entrypoint and troubleshoot from there using the following:

```
# Assuming you have /bin/bash
docker run -it --entrypoint "/bin/bash" myimagename:myimagetag
```

You should be able to get into the container from here with your app added to it and then run the `java` command in your entrypoint which is likely the issue (which may be failing silently).

Comment: (If you change ENTRYPOINT to CMD in the `Dockerfile`, the simpler debug-shell invocation in the @BouzidZitouni's answer will work.)