# Docker Container Stops immediately after starting using run command

Tags: docker, docker-run

I am trying to run locally on Windows Desktop a micro service in Docker (Windows Desktop Docker) and my docker file content is as below:

```
FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/core/aspnet:3.0
WORKDIR /app
COPY . .
EXPOSE 80
ENTRYPOINT ["dotnet", "ScheduleService.dll"]
```

when i issue docker run command to expose port 8081:80 using the following command, the container exits automatically. the run command being issued on Powershell is as below:

```
docker run -d -p 8081:80 schedule
```

When i check the docker using `docker ps -a` command i get the following output:

```
CONTAINER ID        IMAGE               COMMAND                  CREATED             STATUS                              PORTS               NAMES
8d2869a886f9        schedule            "dotnet ScheduleServ…"   7 seconds ago       Exited (2147516561) 4 seconds ago                       gracious_joliot
f2c7e9b43b0b        schedule            "dotnet ScheduleServ…"   19 hours ago        Exited (2147516561) 19 hours ago                        pedantic_cerf
```

It says Exited. can anyone help me on this.

Comment: check the logs `docker logs <container-id>` where container-id can be retrieved from docker ps output.

Comment: https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode/issues/6312 check this out

Comment: Just drop the `-d` parameter and check what's printed out.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why docker container exits immediately](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28212380/why-docker-container-exits-immediately)

Comment: @bellackn on removing -d and issuing command docker run -p 8081:80 schedule, the following message is printed, i guess some issue with ASP .NET Core 3 which I am using in dockerfile:                                                                     
 It was not possible to find any installed .NET Core SDKs
  Did you mean to run .NET Core SDK commands? Install a .NET Core SDK from:
      https://aka.ms/dotnet-download

Comment: Then you've got a detailed answer on what's going wrong. :)

Comment: @bellackn thanks a lot. I guess this error due to final version of .NET core 3.0 still not released and published as Docker image. However how do i spin a docker container for aspnet core 3.0. Do we have to wait till the final release of .net core 3.0