# why does docker ps shows empty containers

Tags: docker

I start with

```
docker run rasa/rasa
```

as tutorials from Youtube suggest.

but when I do

```
docker ps
```

it shows empty list of containers. I thought `run` command should start container processing. 
Why is doesnt start? What am I doing wrong?

Also

```
docker ps -a
```

shows me a giant list of exited containers, but I didn't exit them.

[image]

Comment: Seems like this image runs `rasa --help` by default, which just prints the help message and exits.

Comment: Try to read the logs of the containers so you can check why is the status `Exited`

Comment: @Carlos I tried docker logs ec9d02a3b9f1, but it only showed me the same help message from rasa

Comment: A container exits when its entrypoint/cmd is completed. Thus the `rasa` container executes `rasa --help` prints some help messages and when this is finished, it exits normally(`0` as exit code).

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why docker container exits immediately](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28212380/why-docker-container-exits-immediately)

Answer (score 0):

With command `docker ps -a` command shows you all the containers running/stopped/exited. These are the containers that you tried to run but somehow due to some internal errors those container got stopped and are not running anymore and it shows the status exited(not running).

With command `docker ps`, it shows only running containers. As no containers are running on your machine thats why it is not showing anything. It requires `-a` argument to show you the all containers like `docker ps -a` (Show all containers).

Comment: Yes, I understand that. But the question is why docker run doesn't run container and container is exited even if I didn't provide any further command to it

Comment: actually docker try to run your container but may be due to some bug in your dockerfile it gets exit.