# Why Docker container always exited after start?

Tags: docker, dockerfile

I'm a new to Docker. Tried to start docker container with simple java code.

I saw the printing `Hello-World`, that means that my code is executed, but the container always exits.

This is my Dockerfile:

```
FROM nicb/alpine-openjdk8-jre
COPY HelloDockerTest.jar /
CMD java -jar HelloDockerTest.jar
```

`FROM nicb/alpine-openjdk8-jre` - this is image from remote repository

The steps that I do are:

```
1. docker build -t testtt .
2. docker run -i testtt
3. docker start 2520e85b333a
```

In the last step I see the printing "Hello World" but when I do `docker ps` I see nothing.

What did I do wrong?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why docker container exits immediately](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28212380/why-docker-container-exits-immediately)

Comment: You don't do nothing incorrect, that's the way it should be. The docker executes the commands and then ... it's gone.

Answer (score 0):

This is the correct expected behaviour of Docker. The `ENTRYPOINT` or `CMD` (for the most part) should run a command that runs forever or until a failure scenario occurs.

If you were to change your `CMD` line to `CMD java -jar HelloDockerTest.jar && tail -f /dev/null` your container wouldn't exit. Or if you had started a java application that continues to run, you will see the same behaviour.