# Impossible to start a script into my docker container

Tags: bash, docker, syntax, dockerfile, entry-point

I am trying to create my own image based on Centos. 
I don't understand why when I use CMD command in my docker file to execute a script at startup, it's impossible to start my image (Exited (0) immediatly). 
If build without the CMD command and then I connect to the container and I execute "sh /opt/jbossEAP/Mock/scripts/mock_start.sh". I have no issue
I have tryied to use entrypoint command but same result :(

```
FROM centos:7
ENV container docker
RUN (cd /lib/systemd/system/sysinit.target.wants/; for i in *; do [ $i == \
systemd-tmpfiles-setup.service ] || rm -f $i; done); \
rm -f /lib/systemd/system/multi-user.target.wants/*;\
rm -f /etc/systemd/system/*.wants/*;\
rm -f /lib/systemd/system/local-fs.target.wants/*; \
rm -f /lib/systemd/system/sockets.target.wants/*udev*; \
rm -f /lib/systemd/system/sockets.target.wants/*initctl*; \
rm -f /lib/systemd/system/basic.target.wants/*;\
rm -f /lib/systemd/system/anaconda.target.wants/*;
VOLUME [ "/sys/fs/cgroup" ]
CMD ["/usr/sbin/init"]
RUN yum update -y
RUN mkdir -p /opt/jbossEAP/Mock/scripts/
ADD ./scripts /opt/jbossEAP/Mock/scripts/
RUN chmod +x /opt/jbossEAP/Mock/scripts/mock_start.sh

### START SCRIPT ###
CMD sh /opt/jbossEAP/Mock/scripts/mock_start.sh
```

mock_start.sh

```
#!/bin/sh
############################################
echo "hello"
```

Comment: Your container starts, print hello, and exits immediately (the script ends). It's possible to start the image with different command....

Answer (score 0):

I suspect your CMD or ENTRYPOINT **does** work, but that the container simply finishes after outputting `hello`

You can check your docker's output even after it has been stopped with:
`docker logs <container-id>`

Read https://stackoverflow.com/a/28214133/4486184 for more information on how it works and how to avoid that.

My guesses could be wrong, so please always add to your question:

- How you start your docker image
- `docker ps -a`'s output
- the relevant part of `docker logs <container-id>`'s output

Answer (score 0):

You're right!!!

I just add and now it's ok.

CMD sh /opt/jbossEAP/Mock/scripts/mock_start.sh && tail -f /dev/null

Thank you very much