# Docker container exit immediately

Tags: docker

I've troubles with Docker EE, I've successfully started last week 3 containers I've made, now I need to run a simple nodejs container, I did. `docker run -d node` but it exists immediately and I've got the following error

> time="2020-11-16T11:25:05+01:00" level=error msg="Error waiting for container: failed to shutdown container: container 8a5e6905d6432a9e0ab4dc46b50654e6afe4a6f297dd478d4b07b0dd69e00009 encountered an error during hcsshim::System::waitBackground: failure in a Windows system call: The virtual machine or container with the specified identifier is not running. (0xc0370110): subsequent terminate failed container 8a5e6905d6432a9e0ab4dc46b50654e6afe4a6f297dd478d4b07b0dd69e00009 encountered an error during hcsshim::System::waitBackground: failure in a Windows system call: The virtual machine or container with the specified identifier is not running. (0xc0370110)"

I'm under Windows 2019 Server Standard. Where can I start looking at?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why docker container exits immediately](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28212380/why-docker-container-exits-immediately)

Comment: no, since on docker for windows...it stays alive.

Comment: Note: I have no experience with docker on windows. What happens if you start the container without the -d flag (for daemonizing)? Does the node process stop? It sounds like the last command in your container is an event rather than a loop or server. I find it odd that containers are "alive" on windows even after crashing. The golden rule is that the container runs so long as the last proces is running. If not, it should die immediately. Aren't you confusing "alive" with "inactive"?

Comment: could you give a bit more information on this issue? Docker version, basic image, Dockerfile?