# How to run amd64 docker image on arm64 host platform?

Tags: macos, docker, containers, x86-64, apple-silicon

I have an m1 mac and I am trying to run a amd64 based docker image on my arm64 based host platform. However, when I try to do so (with docker run) I get the following error:

```
WARNING: The requested image's platform (linux/amd64) does not
 match the detected host platform (linux/arm64/v8)
 and no specific platform was requested.
```

When I try adding the tag `--platform linux/amd64` the error message doesn't appear, but I can't seem to go into the relevant shell and `docker ps -a` shows that the container is immediately exited upon starting. Would anyone know how I can run this exact image on my machine given the circumstances/how to make the `--platform` tag work?

Answer (score 135, accepted):

Using `--platform` is correct. On my M1 Mac I'm able to run both arm64 and amd64 versions of the Ubuntu image from Docker Hub. The machine hardware name provided by uname proves it.

```
# docker run --rm -ti --platform linux/arm/v7 ubuntu:latest uname -m
armv7l

# docker run --rm -ti --platform linux/amd64 ubuntu:latest uname -m
x86_64
```

Running amd64 images is enabled by Rosetta2 emulation, as indicated [here](https://docs.docker.com/docker-for-mac/apple-silicon/).

> Not all images are available for ARM64 architecture. You can add `--platform linux/amd64` to run an Intel image under emulation.

If the container is exiting immediately, that's a problem with the specific container you're using.

Comment: Thank you so much for that last part - I just want to use a pre-made Docker container for development and don't _care_ that it won't be as fast, just want it to work. Thank you for telling me how to force it.

Comment: How can I get this to work with docker-compose up ?

Comment: @OamarKanji just add `platform: linux/amd64` in your Compose file

Comment: Warning to others: having the `--platform linux/amd64` at the end of the command does not work - it seems to be best placed before declaring the image name!

Comment: Is this true? If so why would [this issue be open](https://github.com/docker/roadmap/issues/384)?

Comment: Does not work for me when I have the uname part in. But when I remove the uname and what follows after it works like a charm :)

Comment: also possible to set via `export DOCKER_DEFAULT_PLATFORM="linux/amd64"`
if the docker-compose file does not specify this
But unfortunately the emaulation give 32 bit cpu as of now

Comment: Hrmmmm... I built the image this way, tried to run it, but I docker cannot find the image, even if the hash is specified. Docker v20.10

Answer (score 18):

Ensure that `--platform linux/amd64` is immediately after `run`, otherwise it may not work. Correct:

```
docker run --platform linux/amd64 image_name
```

Answer (score 2):

To address the problem of your container immediately exiting after starting, try using the [entrypoint flag](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/#entrypoint) to overwrite the container's entry point. It would look something like this:

```
docker run -it --entrypoint=/bin/bash image_name
```

Credit goes to [this other SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55242665/) that helped me solve a similar issue on my own container.