# Can't start container in Apple M1 after composing image in windows

Tags: c#, docker, docker-compose, apple-m1

I want to create an image on docker with my custom database on it. Basically load an Azure-Sql-Edge image on docker, restore a database on it, compose it to image, and upload it for everyone to use.

I've tried automating this in C# and got to this point:

- Pull the Azure-Sql-Edge image from public repository
- Create a container with the image
- Connect to it and restore my database
- Compose the container back to image
- Push it to a repository

All of this is successful. My problem is the following:

I've picked azure-sql-edge on purpose because it can be run on Apple M1 processors. I use Windows, but some other people might not have windows, so I wanted the image to be able to run on Apple M1 CPU too.

The vanilla image from microsoft Azure-Sql-Edge runs both on Windows(e.g. intel x64) and M1. After I compose my container (from my windows machine), the new image can run on a Apple M1 machine anymore.

Is there something to specify during COMPOSE? Like, a property or something to explicitly say "compose this for ANY cpu"?

Do I need an apple machine to be able to compose the image for M1 too or...

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67458621/how-to-run-amd64-docker-images-on-arm64-host-platform

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65456814/docker-apple-silicon-m1-preview-mysql-no-matching-manifest-for-linux-arm64-v8

Comment: @OneCricketeer I just saw those answers, but I don't understand. I'm using an image that is "supposedly" for both CPUs. When pulling the image, you get the same image that works on both (unless it reads the specs (cpu etc) and pulls the compatible one?).

Comment: How microsoft managed to create an image that works bot on x64 and M1, but when I build it, it becomes platform specific. 

Do I need to specify CPU model during compose?

Comment: It's not possible for an amd64 image to run on arm64 chip without emulation which is what the `platform` flag in the second link shows.

Comment: I will give it a go and return. Thanks