# Running docker amd64 images on arm64 architecture (Apple M1) without rebuilding

Tags: docker, apple-m1, arm64

I have recently got a new MacBook Pro with the M1 chip.
I was trying to run some docker images, but I received some errors:

```
$ docker pull mariadb:5.5
5.5: Pulling from library/mariadb
no matching manifest for linux/arm64/v8 in the manifest list entries
```

```
$ docker run custom-mariadb-build-based-5.5:latest
WARNING: The requested image's platform (linux/amd64) does not match the detected host platform (linux/arm64/v8) and no specific platform was requested
runtime: failed to create new OS thread (have 2 already; errno=22)
```

I have also other (non-mariaDB) images that have the same problem. Running them with the `--platform=linux/amd64` does not make any difference (besides removing the warning).

I know that there are already similar questions here. They have answers to rebuild the images on the new architecture. However, this is currently not possible and I also need to have that specific version of mariaDB, which doesn't support arm64 yet.

I guess that I am not the only one running into this problem and I am wondering how others fixed it. I already tried to use some virtualisation with colima or rancher, but this didn't work.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [how to run amd64 docker images on arm64 host platform](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67458621/how-to-run-amd64-docker-images-on-arm64-host-platform)

Comment: I have installed Rosetta2 but that doesn't seem to change anything:
`$ docker run --platform=linux/amd64 mariadb:5.5
runtime: failed to create new OS thread (have 2 already; errno=22)
fatal error: newosproc`

Comment: this is a known issue:https://github.com/linuxkit/linuxkit/issues/1348

Answer (score 0):

run this command, it works for me.

docker run --privileged --rm tonistiigi/binfmt --install amd64
docker run -it --platform=linux/amd64  --name fdb_non_root_test